# Getting error while running local docker registry

Tags: docker

I am getting while running local docker registry on centos system. I am explaining the error below.

`docker: Error response from daemon: lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3202584ed599bad99c7896e0363ac9bb80a0385910844ce13e9c5e8849494d07: no such file or directory.`

I am setting of the local registry like below.

> vi /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{ "insecure-registries":["ip:5000"] }
```

I have the registry image installed my system and I am running using the below command.

```
docker run -dit -p 5000:5000 --name registry bundle/tools:registry_3.0.0-521
```

I have cleaned all volume as per some suggestion from google but still same issue. Can anybody help me to resolve this error.

Comment: The error is not related to the registry, but local caching of your client system. On your local client system, **if you don't care about your current containers and images and caches**, try stopping the docker daemon, removing the whole `/var/lib/docker` directory, and starting it again.

Comment: Yes, I am ready to remove all container and images. Can you please post the steps for you solutions.

Comment: @AliTou, I have already tried with `docker rm -vf $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -aq)
docker volume prune -f` command but still same issue facing. if you have any new solution can you please guide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not related to the registry and is happening in the client side because of local caching (or some other docker-related issue) in your system.
I've seen this error a lot in the docker community and the most suggested approach to solve this error is to clean up the whole `/var/lib/docker` directory.

On your local client system, **if you don't care about your current containers, images, and caches**, try stopping the docker daemon, removing the whole /var/lib/docker directory, and starting it again:
Note that sometimes it gets fixed by only restarting the daemon, so it worths trying it first:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

If a simple restart can't solve the problem, go ahead and destroy it:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
```

(I'm not sure about if these systemd commands will work on your CentOS too)